# Typescript:could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'import

Tags: typescript

Domain:

```
export interface IDepartamentProps {
  departament_name: string;
  manager_id: string;
}
export class Departament extends AggregateRoot<IDepartamentProps> {
  get DepartamentName(): string {
    return this.props.departament_name;
  }
  get ManagerID(): string {
    return this.props.manager_id;
  }
  private constructor(props: IDepartamentProps, id?: string) {
    super(props, id);
  }
  public static create = async (
    props: IDepartamentProps,
    id?: string,
  ): Promise<Departament> => {
    const guardedProps = [
      { argument: props.departament_name, argumentName: 'departament_name' },
      { argument: props.manager_id, argumentName: 'manager_id' },
    ];
    const guardResult = Guard.againstNullOrUndefinedBulk(guardedProps);
    if (!guardResult.succeeded) throw new Error(guardResult.message);
    const departament = new Departament(props, id);
    const idWasProvided = !!id;
    if (!idWasProvided) {
      departament.when(new LocationCreatedEvent(departament));
    }
    return departament;
  };
}
```

my mapper:

```
export class DepartamentMapper<Departament> implements IMapper<Departament> {
  constructor(private departamentCreator: DomainCreator<Departament>) {}
  toPersistence(t: any): Departament {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  public toDomain = (raw: any): Departament => {
    if (raw instanceof Departament) return raw;
  };
}
```

But for some reason I am getting error when checking if the value is an instance of my Department:

> if (raw instanceof Departament) return raw;

i got this:

> Departament' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could
> be unrelated to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems that I see right away.

#### Problem

`class DepartamentMapper<Departament>` takes a generic with the name `Department`.  The value of this generic has no relation to your class `Department`, but you've given them the same name.  This is why you are getting an error in the `toDomain` method.

```
  public toDomain = (raw: any): Departament => {
    if (raw instanceof Departament) return raw;
  };
```

When you call `raw instanceof Departament` you are checking if it is an instance of the **class** `Department`.  But your return type `Department` is declaring that it is of the **generic** `Department`, which could be anything.

#### Possible Solutions

If `DepartmentMapper` only maps `Department` class objects, then it should not be a generic class. Change the signature to `export class DepartamentMapper implements IMapper<Departament>`.

If `<Department>` is truly a generic, then you need to rethink how you are verifying its type.

#### Problem

In this same function you have another error which is the return type. You return `raw` when you have verified that it is a `Department`, but you do nothing if it's not.  So you get error 2366 "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'".

#### Possible Solutions

1. change the return type to `Department | undefined`
2. throw an `Error` if `raw` is not a `Department`
3. make this into a [guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which is basically a boolean that narrows the type of the input when `true`.  It's kind of trivially simple in this case and doesn't depend on the instance so it could be static. But here's what such a method would look like:

```
public isDepartment = (raw: any): raw is Departament => {
    return raw instanceof Departament;
};
```